# Consulta baseando-se no relacionamento, usando NSPredicate no Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Eu tenho uma relação de um para muitos entre as entidades `Pai` e `Filho`, onde um `Pai` pode ter nenhum ou N `Filho`.
Utilizando o `Core Data`, como faço para buscar todos os `Filho`, baseando minha busca por um `Pai`.

Por exemplo:
Tenho um `Pai` que possui o `Id` 1. Eu preciso buscar todos os `Filho` que tem o `Pai` com o `Id` 1.

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar os nomes das propriedades, tanto da entidade quanto do relacionamento na condição do `NSPredicate` para fazer a requisição.

**Swift**:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Filho")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "RelacionamentoPai.Id == %d", 1)
```

**Objective-C**:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Filho"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"RelacionamentoPai.Id == %d", 1]];
```

Comment: Blz, e no caso de ser um relacionamento muitos para muitos? Isso não existe mas suponhamos que exista, seria através da tabela intermediária que o próprio Core Data cria?

Comment: Em relação `to-many`se usa a palavra-chave `any`.

Exemplo: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY RelacionamentoPai.Id == %d", 1];`